# Energy of an Electron in a One Dimensional Periodic Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation

First, we consider the time independent Schrodinger equation of the form:
$$\bigg(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+u(x) \bigg)\phi_A(x)=E_A\phi_A(x)$$
Where $u(x)$ is a potential created by a single ion (of a one dimensional single ion crystal lattice).  Then now we expand the case from a single ion case to a $M$ ion case $(M>>1)$ in which the Schrodinger equation is given by :

$$\bigg(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+U(x) \bigg)\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$$ 
with boundary conditions: $$\psi(x)=\psi(x+Ma)$$

where 
$$ U(x)= \sum\limits_{j=1}^M u(x-ja)$$
$$ \psi_k(x)= \sum\limits_{j=1}^M e^{ik(ja)}\phi_A(x-ja)$$

In this problem, I am trying to solve for the Hamiltonian Eigenvalue $E(k)$ for $\psi_k(x)$ through integrating the Schrodinger equation after multiplying it with the complex conjugate $\phi^*_A(x)$ as shown as follows:

$$\bigg\langle\phi_A(x)\bigg|-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+U(x)\bigg|\psi_k(x)\bigg\rangle = E\langle\phi_A(x)|\psi_k(x)\rangle$$

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^M\bigg\langle\phi_A(x)\bigg|-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+U(x)\bigg|e^{ik(ja)}\phi_A(x-ja)\bigg\rangle = E\sum\limits_{j=1}^M\langle\phi_A(x)|e^{ik(ja)}\phi_A(x-ja)\rangle$$

I am stuck here. What would be my next step in solving for the Energy  $E(k)$ using the following relationships:

$$\langle\phi_A(x-ma)|\phi_A(x-na)\rangle = \delta_{mn}$$
$$\beta=\langle\phi_A(x)|u(x\pm na)|\phi_A(x)\rangle$$
$$\gamma=\langle\phi_A(x)|u(x)|\phi_A(x\pm a)\rangle$$

Comment: Have you considered solving this problem in k space?

Comment: How would I solve this problem in k-space? I noticed that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ integrals of this case represent the tight-binding matrix elements of the Tight-Binding model. However, I am not sure of how to apply it to this case.

Comment: The introduction of $/exp(ik)$ I suspect is there to lead you to a Fourier transform.

Comment: Of course the Fourier Transform of a periodic function reduces to Fourier Analysis, with integer values of k, coraspond to Eigenfunctions.

Comment: The last step is the actual integration. Given the form of the transformed wavefunction, each k value forms an orthogonal basis.